# emulate unix 'cut' using standard windows command line/batch commands

Tags: windows, unix, command-line

Is there a way to emulate the unix cut command on windows XP, without resorting to cygwin or other non-standard windows capabilities?

Example: Use tasklist /v, find the specific task by the window title, then extract the PID from that list to pass to taskkill.

Comment: Thanks. The tokens & delims do a fair emulation of cut - just a pain to have to clutter the batch file with unrequired for loops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FYI, tasklist and taskkill already have filtering capabilities:

```
tasklist /FI "imagename eq chrome.exe"
taskkill /F /FI "imagename eq iexplore.exe"
```

If you want more general functionality, batch scripts (ugh) can help. For example:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ('tasklist /v') do (
  if "%%i" == "%~1" (
    echo TASKKILL /PID %%j
  )
)
```

There's a fair amount of help for the windows command-line. Type "help" to get a list of commands with a simple summary then type "help " for more information about that command (e.g. "help for").