# Is there an equivalent to 'cut -c' in Windows cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have some files of fixed line size, fixed field size that I need to extract information from. Nornmally, I'd use Cygwin (`cut` et al), but that's not an option in this case due to (boneheaded) management policies I can't change. It *has* to be done using standard XP toolset included with Windows.

I need to extract the 10 characters at offset 7 and 4 characters at offset 22 (zero-based), and output them to a file but with a slight twist:

- The first field may have a negative, positive, or no sign (at the start or end). The sign should be moved to the front, or removed totally if it's positive.
- The second field should have leading and trailing spaces removed.

For example:

```
          1         2         3          <- ignore (these lines not in file,)
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789 <- ignore ( here only for info.)
xxxxxxx    15.22-yyyyyABCDzzzzzzzzzzz...
xxxxxxx   122.00+yyyyy XX zzzzzzzzzzz...
xxxxxxx         9yyyyyYYY zzzzzzzzzzz...
```

should produce (`<` indicates end of line):

```
-15.22,ABCD<
122.00,XX<
9,YYY<
```

Comment: Related: [emulate unix 'cut' using standard windows command line/batch commands](http://stackoverflow.com/q/98363/95735)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you working with modern windows, you are not restricted to cmd.exe commands natively, you can use vbscript. If your policy is not to use vbscript either, then I guess you should sack your management :)

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "c:\test\file"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
strFirstLine = objFile.ReadLine
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine= objFile.ReadLine
    var1 = Mid(strLine,10) ' do substring from position 10 onwards
    ' var2 = Mid (strLine,<pos>,<length>) ' get next offset and save to var2
    WScript.Echo var1 & var2  ' print them out.
Loop
```

Basically, to "cut" characters of a string, you use Mid() function. please look at the [vbscript documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C717D943-7E4B-4622-86EB-95A22B832CAA&displaylang=en) to find out more.

Save the above as test.vbs and, on the command line, do

```
c:\test> cscript /nologo test.vbs > newfile
```

Of course, "substring" can also be done with pure cmd.exe but I will leave it to some others to guide you.

*Update by Pax:* Based on this answer, I came up with the following which will be a good start:

```
option explicit
dim objFs, objFile, strLine, value1, value2

if wscript.arguments.count < 1 then
    wscript.echo "Usage: process <input-file>"
    wscript.quit
end if

set objFs=createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFile = objFs.openTextFile(wscript.arguments.item(0))
do  until objFile.atEndOfStream
    strLine= objFile.readLine
    value1 = trim(mid(strLine, 8, 10))
    value2 = trim(mid(strLine, 23, 4))
    if right(value1,1) = "-" then value1 = "-" & left(value1,len(value1)-1)
    if right(value1,1) = "+" then value1 = left(value1,len(value1)-1)
    if left(value1,1) = "+" then value1 = mid(value1,2)
    wscript.echo value1 & "," & value2
loop
```

This matches all the requirements we had. We can make the offsets and lengths into command-line arguments later.

*End update.*

Comment: Unfortunately, not my management, this was for a friend. But vbscript is a good point, they're using XP. Perhaps I should clarify that.

Comment: Thanks, @ghostdog, much obliged. I've added the code I'm sending through since it handles the other requirements as well. +1 and accept. Cheers.

Comment: `'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

If things can be installed, one wouldn't have been asking specifically about cmd.exe

Answer (score 6):

This site has some pointers on how to extract substrings in cmd.exe: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

That site suggests that you can use

```
%varname:~2,3%
```

to subscript a variable. This seems to fill your needs, except you now have to get each line into a variable.

Next you want to look at the ghastly `for` loop syntax and `if` and branching (you can goto `:labels` in batch).

This stuff is all rather ugly, but if you really have to go there...

Here is a page in SO on looping through files and doing stuff to them: [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Thanks, @Daren. It turns out that VBScript will be far easier. +1 for the answer anyway.

Comment: yup. I would avoid cmd.exe wherever possible (I was tempted to see if I could post some source, but then... it's just plain ghastly!)

Comment: Daren: Hey, don't insult languaes with unfamiliar syntax. You can do great things in batch files and for some people it's actually fun (admitted, those are usually the same people who delight in solving problems with Brainfuck or SNUSP).

Comment: @Johannes: A language can be both useful (to get things done) and ghastly at the same time. These are orthogonal concepts. As to fun... there are a lot of really weird people out there (about one in twenty).

Comment: Okay, but `cut` works in a pipeline, and trying to put the source pipe into the for loop just give an error: `| was unexpected at this time.`

Which is extra frustrating since only windows fails in this additional way.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a small script (needs to be in a BAT/CMD file) expanding on what Daren Thomas suggested:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Stats\{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}\iexplore\AllowedDomains

echo.
echo Liste der fuer Flash im IE zugelassenen Domaenen:
echo =================================================
for /f "usebackq tokens=11 delims=\" %%l in (`call reg query "%key%" /s`) do echo. %%l
echo.
endlocal
```

The FOR loop is the central part. Note the use of command modifiers in double quotes. I specify `tokens=11` because I'm only interested in the subkeys of `AllowedDomains`, which is at position 10.

Be sure to read the help in `for /?`. Daren is right when he says this stuff is all rather ugly. And it easily breaks down on modification. There's a lot of non-intuitive subtleties with `cmd.exe` script syntax.

By the way, the GUID is the COM class ID for the Shockwave Flash Add-on. It's [been around since at least 2001](https://www.google.com/search?q=D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000) so might well continue to be relevant for the foreseeable future. The purpose of the script is to list the domains where [Flash, which I prefer to block by default](https://superuser.com/q/828913/69392), has been allowed.